# python matplotlib histogram specify different colours for different bars

Tags: python, matplotlib, histogram

I want to colour different bars in a histogram based on which bin they belong to.  e.g. in the below example, I want the first 3 bars to be blue, the next 2 to be red, and the rest black (the actual bars and colour is determined by other parts of the code).

I can change the colour of all the bars using the color option, but I would like to be able to give a list of colours that are used.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = np.random.rand(1000)
plt.hist(data,color = 'r')
```

Comment: If you know how many bins there are and what color they should be then `hist` accepts a list of colors

Comment: @DavidG can you show me how?  I tried to do this and it didn't work.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

One way may be similar to approach in [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43872450/matplotlib-histogram-with-legend):

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
data = np.random.rand(1000)

N, bins, patches = ax.hist(data, edgecolor='white', linewidth=1)

for i in range(0,3):
    patches[i].set_facecolor('b')
for i in range(3,5):    
    patches[i].set_facecolor('r')
for i in range(5, len(patches)):
    patches[i].set_facecolor('black')

plt.show()
```

Result:

[image]