# How to create a histogram where each bar is a heatmap of the corresponding bin?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have a dataframe:

```
df.head()[['price', 'volumen']]

    price   volumen
48  45      3
49  48      1
50  100     2
51  45      1
52  56      1
```

It represents the number of objects with particular price.
I created a histogram based on the `volume` column:

[image]

I would like to add information about the price distribution of each bin. My idea is to use heatmaps instead of single-color columns. E.g. a color red will show a high price, and yellow a low price.

Here is an example plot to illustrate the general idea:

[image]

Comment: This is a task, not a question. And not even a well-defined task. How do you define low price and high price? What was your coding approach, where did it fail? [Similar questions have](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43873315/8881141) also [been asked before.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49290555/8881141) Did you try to implement them?

Comment: @Mr.T I would like to have multiple colors inside one bin. Colors should represent price range inside it

Comment: @JohanC I saw it. If I understood correctly it create standard heat map, I looking for something different

Comment: Why would it have different colors inside a bar? As I understand your question, the x-axis represents the price.

Comment: @Mr.T no it should be a histogram, so x axis represent how many object I have in `volumen` column. This histogram based on a code ```df['volumen'].plot.hist()``` .
So I would like to add representation of each bin about prices inside it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following example uses seaborn's tips dataset. A histogram is created by grouping the `total_bill` into bins. And then the bars are colored depending on the tips in each group.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.patches as mpatches
import seaborn as sns

sns.set_theme(style='white')
tips = sns.load_dataset('tips')
tips['bin'] = pd.cut(tips['total_bill'], 10)  # histogram bin

grouped = tips.groupby('bin')

min_tip = tips['tip'].min()
max_tip = tips['tip'].max()
cmap = 'RdYlGn_r'
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(12, 4))
for bin, binned_df in grouped:
    bin_height = len(binned_df)
    binned_tips = np.sort(binned_df['tip']).reshape(-1, 1)
    ax.imshow(binned_tips, cmap=cmap, vmin=min_tip, vmax=max_tip, extent=[bin.left, bin.right, 0, bin_height],
              origin='lower', aspect='auto')
    ax.add_patch(mpatches.Rectangle((bin.left, 0), bin.length, bin_height, fc='none', ec='k', lw=1))

ax.autoscale()
ax.set_ylim(0, 1.05 * ax.get_ylim()[1])
ax.set_xlabel('total bill')
ax.set_ylabel('frequency')
plt.colorbar(ax.images[0], ax=ax, label='tip')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Here is how it looks with a banded colormap (`cmap = plt.get_cmap('Spectral', 9)`):

[image: banded colormap]

Here is another example using the `'mpg'` dataset, with a histogram over car weight and coloring via mile-per-gallon.

[image: mpg example]

Answer (score 1):

You can generate a heat map using Seaborn. bin / shape the dataframe first.  This is random data so heat map is not so interesting.

```
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

s = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({"price":np.random.randint(30,120, s),"volume":np.random.randint(1,5, s)})

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2, figsize=[10,6])

df.loc[:,"volume"].plot(ax=ax[0], kind="hist", bins=3)
# reshape for a heatmap... put price into bins and make 2D
dfh = df.assign(pbin=pd.qcut(df.price,5)).groupby(["pbin","volume"]).mean().unstack(1).droplevel(0,axis=1)
axh = sns.heatmap(dfh, ax=ax[1])
```

[image]